# Access a Parent's Enumeration

Tags: python, inheritance, enums, class-attributes

I have a diagnostic class (technically a `@dataclass` written in python). The diagnostic class currently has a class method corresponding to the diagnostic message's "level" (ie info, warning, error). It also has an enumeration, Level:

```
@dataclass
class Diagnostic:
    #instance variables bc dataclass
    severity: Level
    message: str
    start: Tuple[int, int]
    end: Tuple[int, int]

    class Level(enum.IntEnum):
        info = 0
        error = 1
        warning = 2
        #....

@classmethod
    def create(...)
        #....

@classmethod
    def info(...)
        #....

@classmethod
    def warning(...)
        #....

@classmethod
    def error(...)
        #....
```

**I'd like to alter this so that each diagnostic message has its own class.** So far I came up with this hierarchy, where `Diagnostic_Error`, `Diagnostic_Info`, and `Diagnostic_Warning` are children of `Diagnostic` class (which is no longer a `dataclass`):

```
class Diagnostic:
    # instance properties
    __slots__ = ("message", "start", "end")

    def __init__(
        self, message: str, start: Tuple[int, int], end: Tuple[int, int]
    ) -> None:
        self.message = message
        self.start = start
        self.end = end

    class Level(enum.IntEnum):
        info = 0
        error = 1
        warning = 2

        # but do we still need this?
        @classmethod
        def from_docutils(cls, docutils_level: int) -> "Diagnostic.Level":
            level = docutils_level - 1
            level = min(level, cls.warning)
            level = max(level, cls.info)
            return cls(level)


class Diagnostic_Info(Diagnostic):
    severity: Diagnostic.Level = Level.info


class Diagnostic_Warning(Diagnostic):
    severity: Diagnostic.Level = Level.warning


class Diagnostic_Error(Diagnostic):
    severity: Diagnostic.Level = Level.error
```

However, I am getting `Name 'Level' is not defined`.

**How do I access the parent's enumeration from the child class? In this case, how do I access Level from Diagnostic_Error, Diagnostic_Info, and Diagnostic_Warning ?**

Comment: `Level` isn't defined in the global scope; it's a class attribute. `severity: Diagnostic.Level = Diagonistic.Level.info`, etc.

Comment: @chepner - maybe I don't follow. Even with `Diagnostic.Level = Diagonistic.Level.info` I still get `Name 'Level' is not defined`

Answer (score -1):

You are using `Diagnostic.Level` in the type hint, but only `Level` in the value to assign to `severity`. `Level` is an attribute of `Diagnostic` in both cases.

```
class Diagnostic_Info(Diagnostic):
    severity: Diagnostic.Level = Diagnostic.Level.info
```